# Why does authtest fisrtneme.lastneme@mydomain.tld password do not work on MySQL based email server on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, postfix, courier

I used this manual for dummies for configure email sever for Ubuntu 20.04:

https://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-14.04-lts

And for passwords ENCRYPT function on MySQL is removed from my MySQL Server version.

How to make password crypt right way for virtual users on MySQL?

I tried make password crypt with this manual:

https://www.courier-mta.org/authlib/authpasswd.html

Here is code of users table for MySQL in file mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf:

```
   user = mail_admin
   password = password
   dbname = mail
   query = SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1),'/',SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',1),'/') FROM `users` WHERE email='%s'
   hosts = 127.0.0.1
```

And error of Linux bash command described in this subject:

```
Authentication FAILED: Operation not permitted
```

Here is some error logs:

```
Sep 18 16:25:52 alm authdaemond: authmysql: cannot parse the MYSQL_OPT setting
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to adapt some SQL configuration for current software, so to answer this it would be essential to see what you have attempted and why that did not work or meet your requirements. Please [edit] your question to include relevant configuration, steps attempted, errors logged, ..

Comment: Okay, I edit little bit my question,

Comment: Now I am edited my question best I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this issue solved by my own efforts.

with adding a line below to file authmysqlrc:

MYSQL_OPT 0